Angular Subject : Button Click Event Triggering Multiple Times
I'm encountering an issue in my Angular application where a button click event triggered by a service is being executed multiple times in a subscribing component.
private buttonClickedSource = new Subject<void>();
buttonClicked$ = this.buttonClickedSource.asObservable();

triggerButtonClick() {
  this.buttonClickedSource.next();
}

In my component
subscription: Subscription;
  this.subscription = this.dataservice.buttonClicked$.subscribe(() => {
    this.onButtonClick();
  });

The issue is that this.onButtonClick() gets executed multiple times, sometimes once, sometimes twice, and sometimes 6-7 times.

please share more code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

please share the html where you call the triggerButtonClick method

if you wanna your Subscription close, you should call complete method
otherwise every time your component get created, it subscribe observable again
and every time your component destroy the subscription still remain
so in your case you don't wanna call complete method
you should unsubscribe your observable after your component destory
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}

